# Program not running in eclipse. <terminated> ezMain(Class) (files and time were after this)

Tags: java

Sorry in advance if this is a bad post this is my first post on this website. Working on code finally finished it when i tried to run it after an hour of making the code.(I'm new to GUI I already knew this previously but I was bored so I started writing this also I know I should have stopped to go back and make shore that it worked) In eclipse everything is fine but when I look at the console it says this[1] '

Main class file with constructor

```
package Systems;

public class ezMain {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    eZ z = new eZ();

   }
}
```

package Systems;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Timer;

public class eZ implements ActionListener {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame3 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame4 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame5 = new JFrame();
JButton button = new JButton();
JButton button2 = new JButton();
JButton button3 = new JButton();
JButton button4 = new JButton();
JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
JTextArea area2 = new JTextArea();
JTextArea area3 = new JTextArea();
JTextArea area4 = new JTextArea();
JTextArea area5 = new JTextArea();

        void e() {

            ezMain ff = new ezMain();

        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        frame.setTitle("Who's the Best cat?");

        area.setBounds(400, 0, 150, 75);
        area.setText("Who is the best cat?");

        //.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        button.setBounds(50, 300, 150, 75);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setText("Cheeto");

        button2.setBounds(250, 300, 175, 75);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        button2.setText("Colby");

        button3.setBounds(450, 300, 175, 75);
        button3.addActionListener(this);
        button3.setText("Swirls");

        button4.setBounds(650, 300, 175, 75);
        button4.addActionListener(this);
        button4.setText("Monster");

        frame.add(button);
        frame.add(button2);
        frame.add(button3);
        frame.add(button4);
        frame.add(area);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


         class actionListener implements ActionListener{
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 button.getAction();
                 button2.getAction();
                 button3.getAction();
                 button4.getAction();

                 if(button.getAction() != null)
                    frame2.setSize(600,400);
                    frame2.setVisible(true);
                    frame2.setLayout(null);

                    area2.setBounds(300, 200, 200, 200);
                    area2.setText("Cheeto is an okay cat but he is a 
butt"); 

                    frame2.add(area2);



                     if(button2.getAction() != null)
                            frame3.setSize(800,600);
                            frame3.setVisible(true);
                            frame3.setLayout(null);

                            area3.setBounds(300, 200, 200, 200);
                            area3.setText("Cheeto is an okay cat but he 
             is an"); 

                            frame3.add(area3);

                             if(button3.getAction() != null)
                                    frame4.setSize(800,600);
                                    frame4.setVisible(true);
                                    frame4.setLayout(null);

                                    area4.setBounds(300, 200, 200, 200);
                                    area4.setText("Cheeto is an okay cat 
           but he is a"); 

                                    frame4.add(area4);


                                     if(button4.getAction() != null)
                                            frame5.setSize(800,600);
                                            frame5.setVisible(true);
                                            frame5.setLayout(null);

                                            area5.setBounds(300, 200, 
                 200, 200);
                                            area5.setText("Cheeto is an 
         okay cat but he i"); 

                                            frame5.add(area5);



             }
          }



    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

   }
```

### [Getting Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35aKv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have successfully initialized `eZ` object by calling `new eZ();` But you need to call `e() method` to open Frame.

```
public class ezMain {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    eZ z = new eZ();
    z.e();
   }
}
```

Few Advice:

1. Please make sure to follow all coding standard for Java.
2. Class name should start with UpperCase Letter
3. Follow Package name strategy
4. You can see modified class name and package name below.

CatIdentifier.java

```
package com.cat.frame;

public class CatIdentifier {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       BestCat bestCat = new BestCat();
       bestCat.findBestCat();
    }
}
```

BestCat.java

```
package com.cat.frame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class BestCat implements ActionListener {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame3 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame4 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame5 = new JFrame();
JButton button = new JButton();
JButton button2 = new JButton();
JButton button3 = new JButton();
JButton button4 = new JButton();
JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
JTextArea area2 = new JTextArea();
JTextArea area3 = new JTextArea();
JTextArea area4 = new JTextArea();
JTextArea area5 = new JTextArea();

void findBestCat() {

    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    frame.setTitle("Who's the Best cat?");

    area.setBounds(400, 0, 150, 75);
    area.setText("Who is the best cat?");

    // .setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    button.setBounds(50, 300, 150, 75);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    button.setText("Cheeto");

    button2.setBounds(250, 300, 175, 75);
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    button2.setText("Colby");

    button3.setBounds(450, 300, 175, 75);
    button3.addActionListener(this);
    button3.setText("Swirls");

    button4.setBounds(650, 300, 175, 75);
    button4.addActionListener(this);
    button4.setText("Monster");

    frame.add(button);
    frame.add(button2);
    frame.add(button3);
    frame.add(button4);
    frame.add(area);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    class actionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            button.getAction();
            button2.getAction();
            button3.getAction();
            button4.getAction();

            if (button.getAction() != null)
                frame2.setSize(600, 400);
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.setLayout(null);

            area2.setBounds(300, 200, 200, 200);
            area2.setText("Cheeto is an okay cat but he is a butt");

            frame2.add(area2);

            if (button2.getAction() != null)
                frame3.setSize(800, 600);
            frame3.setVisible(true);
            frame3.setLayout(null);

            area3.setBounds(300, 200, 200, 200);
            area3.setText("Cheeto is an okay cat but he is an");

            frame3.add(area3);

            if (button3.getAction() != null)
                frame4.setSize(800, 600);
            frame4.setVisible(true);
            frame4.setLayout(null);

            area4.setBounds(300, 200, 200, 200);
            area4.setText("Cheeto is an okay cat but he is a");

            frame4.add(area4);

            if (button4.getAction() != null)
                frame5.setSize(800, 600);
            frame5.setVisible(true);
            frame5.setLayout(null);

            area5.setBounds(300, 200, 200, 200);
            area5.setText("Cheeto is an okay cat but he i");

            frame5.add(area5);

        }
    }

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```